# What might cause a block device to somehow be smaller than its partitions?

Tags: linux, partition, dd, block-device

I'm trying to wipe an IOSafe external drive, and I'm running into a major problem.  When I run `dd` to wipe the full disk (`/dev/sdb`) it errors out at the 1.8 GB mark (it's a 2 TB disk), saying no space left on device.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress
```

When I go to wipe `/dev/sdb1` (the partition, that oddly enough shouldn't even exist, because I wiped the partition table), it will wipe that.ea

Any idea what's going on and what to do about it?

Output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.7 GiB, 1770082304 bytes, 3457192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1f7d3f72
```

As requested, the output of ls -l /dev/sdb*

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1770082304 Oct 27 07:17 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8, 17 Oct 27 07:18 /dev/sdb1
```

Now that I see that output, does the 'b' in the sdb1 line denote a block device?

Comment: about 5% of total disk space is reserved on linux systems. That account for 100GB of missing space on your hard drive. Maybe it got consumed by damaged inodes. How old is your hard drive?

Comment: I'm running "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress".  I have the sdb1 wipe (same command otherwise) running right now, it's up to 687GB.

According to fdisk, the sdb device is 1.7GiB, while the sdb1 device is 1.8TiB.  How does this happen?

Comment: Can you include the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb ` in your question?

Comment: Already done now :)

Comment: Hmm. So `fdisk` doesn't show that there are any partitions. Is `/dev/sdb1` a special device file, or an ordinary file?

Comment: How would I tell that?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l /dev/sdb*` to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to the answer to Mark Plotnick's question, it is demonstrated

`/dev/sdb` has been removed as a device node, so you've then filled `/dev` (which is a tmpfs and hence limited by RAM).  As you surmise, the `b` next to `sdb1` is what shows that it's a block device.

`/dev` should be recreated if you reboot.